# Python: List in List which keeps the difference between column position and row position

Tags: python, list

Dear all I am new to programming and I am using Python.

I have the following code:

```
P=[]
i=0
j=0

P=[[0]*5]*5
while i<5:
    for j in range(0,5):
        P[i][j]=i-j
    i=i+1
print(P)
```

And I expect the following output:

[[0, -1, -2,-3, -4], [1, 0, -1, -2, -3], [2, 1, 0, -1, -2], [3, 2, 1, 0, -1], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]

As I would like to keep in the cells the difference between their row number and column.

The program gives the following output:

[[4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]

Thanks in Advance for the help!

Comment: don't have time to post an answer, but this should be dead simple with [enumerate(iterable)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). **In general**, if you find yourself pre-creating lists like arrays in c, and then manually managing i, j, etc. you're still programming in c.

Answer (score 3):

`[[0]*5]*5` creates 5 copies of the list `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. This can be seen through the use of `map` and `id`.

```
>>> list(map(id, [[0]*5]*5))
[58739912, 58739912, 58739912, 58739912, 58739912]
```

Notice that each of the values are identical. This means that every time you change *any one of these lists*, you will change all of them.

The simple solution to this is using a list comprehension.

```
P = [[0]*5 for i in range(5)]
```

Note that this problem only occurs with mutable objects like lists, so it is fine with integers.

---

As a side note, the problem can be solved in a much simpler way.

```
>>> P = [[i for i in range(j, j-5, -1)] for j in range(5)]
>>> P
[[0, -1, -2, -3, -4], [1, 0, -1, -2, -3], [2, 1, 0, -1, -2], [3, 2, 1, 0, -1], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works useing provided methods.
Maybe it is a stupid question, but I just wanted to create the P (the list of lists) to be sufficiently large enough. Why the loop later do not overwrite the values?

Comment: @user2175943 the loop creates separate lists each time, whereas your method created copies of the same list.